# pillow - Adding a png Image to a jpg image

Tags: image, python-imaging-library

[booster.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0vXE.png)

[bg.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnFV2.jpg)

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("bg.jpg").convert('RGBA')
booster = Image.open('booster.png').resize((150, 150)).convert('RGBA')
background.paste(booster, (30, 30))
background.show()
```

The output which I get:

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epavd.png)

Any way to remove that alpha thing from the booster.png?

Comment: Your "booster.png" input image has that check pattern as part of the image. I don't think this is an alpha problem. You need to edit the image first or remove the background computationally

Comment: Agreed. `booster.png` must be an RGBA image with alpha already a part of it.